# java 9 : confusing rules about Resources and modules

Tags: resources, java-9

In module com.thing.withprops I have this code in com.thing.withprops.UseProps.java:

```
 URL url =UseProps.class.getResource("config/values.properties") ;
```

module-info is

```
module com.thing.withprops { exports com.thing.withprops;}
```

now there is another module with name com.thing.withprops.config  where lies a values.properties file in directory com/thing/withprops/config/
the module-info is just this:

```
module com.thing.withprops.config{}
```

well when everything is jarred  and executed all is working perfectly: the resource is found! I am confused because it seems that the doc says it shouldn't be found since it is in another module which is not exported or opened.
So what is wrong? the way I understand doc (I am not a native speaker) or my code?

thanks for any hint

Comment: Sounds like you have created a plain old jar instead of a [“modular JAR”](https://www.google.de/search?q=modular+JAR)…

Comment: no: these jars have their module-info.class at the top (I checked that immediately)

Comment: and you ran the application with the jar on the module path instead of the class path?

Comment: just did "java -jar top.jar" (which is the jar with the main and manifest that describes Class-Path to the other 2 jars) ... is that the problem? then how to have a "java -jar" that behaves correctly?

Comment: [`java [options] [--module-path modulepath] --module module[/mainclass] [args...]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624)

Comment: may be (but not sure since this is what the IntelliJ runs and it runs by delivering the URL ... I will test it from the command line) but how to do that with jars?

Comment: yes the direct command with java fails ... but then how come the jar succeeds?

Comment: `--module-path` resp. `-p` may point to the directory containing your modular jars. `-jar` simply exists for backward compatibility and doesn’t load the jar as a module.

Comment: Just to add to Holger's comment. `java -jar` is for executable JARs, the JAR file is added to the class path. So it's nothing to do with modules.

Comment: where is the fact that -jar is incompatible with modular jar documented? do you mean that if you deploy a jar to be clicked on (the old way) it's not supposed to work anymore? then what do you do to deploy jars simply (not talking of jlink or scripts)?

Answer (score 0):

in fact there are two problems there : one is about handling resources and the other is about java -jar behavior

here is a suggestion on how to handle resources in a modular project:

```
public interface ResourceLoader {
public static Optional<URL> resourceSearch(Class clazz, String name) {
    String fullPath = name ;
    if(! name.startsWith("/")) {
        String packageName = clazz.getPackageName();
        fullPath = '/'+packageName.replace('.','/')+ '/' + name;
    }

    ServiceLoader<ResourceLoader> loader = ServiceLoader.load(ResourceLoader.class);
    for(ResourceLoader resourceLoader: loader) {
        Optional<URL>  anUrl =resourceLoader.getResource(fullPath);
        if(anUrl.isPresent()) {
            return anUrl ;
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty() ;
}

public static Optional<InputStream>  resourceSearchAsStream(Class clazz, String name) throws IOException {
    Optional<URL> anURL = resourceSearch(clazz, name) ;
    if(anURL.isPresent()){
        InputStream is = anURL.get().openStream() ;
        return Optional.of(is) ;
    }
     return Optional.empty() ;
}

public default Optional<URL> getResource(String fullPath) {
    Class localClass = this.getClass() ;
    URL res = localClass.getResource(fullPath) ;
    return Optional.ofNullable(res) ;
}
```

}

then one can deploy another module with resources with module-info like :

```
open module com.thing.withprops.config {
requires com.thing.withprops;
provides com.thing.withprops.utils.ResourceLoader with com.thing.withprops.spi.ResourceLoaderImpl ;
```

}

any other suggestion?
(still trying to find a way to have something looking like a "clickable" jar ...but could be hopeless)